# Java - Equals and Hashcode comparision

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to understand the below scenario of `equals()` and `hashcode()` and here hashcode always returns 1.

- Case-1: if I don't override `equals` and hashcode then I get size=4
- Case-2: If I don't override `equals`, only override `hashcode` always returning 1, then size=4
- Case-3: If I don't override `hashcode`, only override `equals` then size=4
- Case-4: If I override `equals` and `hashcode` both , `hashcode` always returns 1, then size=3
- Case-5: If I override `equals` and `hashcode` both, `hashcode` will be system generated, then size=3

Can somebody explain how its internally and case of each scenario?

Code

```java
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    public class Employee {
        private String name;
        private int age;
    
        public Employee() {
        }
    
        public Employee(String name, int age) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
    //      final int prime = 31;
    //      int result = 1;
    //      result = prime * result + age;
    //      result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return 1;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Employee other = (Employee) obj;
            if (age != other.age)
                return false;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee prateek = new Employee("Prateek", 32);
            Employee prateek1 = new Employee("Prateek", 32);
            Employee savani = new Employee("Savani", 40);
            Employee karan = new Employee("Karan", 18);
            
            Map<Employee, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(prateek, "Prateek");
            map.put(savani, "Savani");
            map.put(prateek1, "Prateek");
            map.put(karan, "Karan");
            
            System.out.println("Size = "+map.size());
            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What were you expecting hashcode to return when its impl is `return 1;`? hashcode and equals are unrelated, except that if equals is true, hashcode *should* also be equal.

Comment: Please read on the internal workings of HashMap and you will get your answer. I do not wish to retype what has already been explained  very at the given link. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/

Comment: I think I'd like you to try to explain these yourself, then ask for corrections as needed.  (I've done that for other questions.)  The fact is the reasons are fairly obvious and you should try to figure them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bohemian's answer is exactly correct.  For example, the following `hashCode()` method fulfills the contract and programs will run correctly:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 42;
}
```

The reason that programs with this method are correct is because the contract for `hashCode()` is fulfilled:  equal instances will always have the same hash code.

But the reason that this `hashCode()` method is a problem is because it returns the same hash for both equal and unequal instances.  For best performance, developers should try to write `hashCode()` methods that generate distinct int values for unequal instances.  This is not required by the contract for `hashCode()` but it is essential if good performance is important.

For example, with the method above, every instance that is added to a `HashMap` will be distributed to the same bucket.  The result is that performance degrades.  The best hash function will do a good job of distributing unequal instances into separate buckets.  For this reason, your case #2 could result in serious performance problems if those instances were used in a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

The contract between [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) is basically: *if equals() is true, hashCode() should return the same value.*

From the javadoc:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

If that isn't the case, behaviour of hash-based collections/operations is undefined.